# From Timestamp obtain datetime object (Python)

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to convert this timestamp time into date. I've tried several functions (`pandas.Timestamp()`) but unsuccessfully.

It seems that the function `datetime.fromtimestamp()` is not able to recognize because of the final zeros (3 zeros). If I delete manually these zeros I'm able to convert the timestamp correctly.

This below is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime


ts_0 = 1640225340000
out_0 = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts_0)  #Invalid Input

#Manually change timestamp -> last three zeros deleted
ts_1 = 1640225340
out_1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts_0) 
#>>> datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 23, 3, 9)
```

If I go to [EpochConverter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) and I copy and paste `ts_0` I will get the correct answer immediatly...

How can I solve this simple task?

Comment: What specifically is your question? "*is not able to recognize*" - code does not do magic. The method is programmed to accept seconds as a floating point number, and that's it. pandas to_datetime has a `unit` keyword that gives you more options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just divide your original timestamp (with the 3 extra zeros) by 1000?

```
from datetime import datetime

ts_0 = 1640225340000
out_0 = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts_0/1000)
```

Comment: yes i got you. But it was just to avoid the shortcut solution, I would like to know why a simple task like this cannot be done by the original functions that were built to perform this task... If you go to https://www.epochconverter.com/ and you copy and paste ts_0 you will get the correct answer without diving by 1000

Comment: Because the extra 3 zeros are **wrong**.  A unix timestamp is the number of seconds since midnight on 1/1970.  Not milliseconds (which is what adding 3 zeros gives you).  epochconverter.com is nice enough to try to figure it out from the scale of the input number, but note even it says "**assuming** milliseconds" when you enter it.  Program functions don't generally assume things for you!

Comment: Representing Unix time as milliseconds since the epoch is perfectly fine, nothing wrong about that. The resolution (unit) and data type chosen just determines the range vs. precision you can represent.

Comment: You can certainly represent Unix time as milliseconds if you want, but that's not what fromtimestep() is expecting.  The documentation specifically states: "Construct a datetime from a POSIX timestamp (like time.time())", and time.time() returns seconds **not** milliseconds.  the epochconverter site has added some code to try to infer the units from the scale of the input, which fromtimestep() does **not** do.